# Is it possible to prototype a subroutine as $$& in perl?

Tags: perl, prototype

Just a curiosity, I have played around with prototyping a bit, but it seems that the prototype `&` for a subroutine is only allowed in the first position.

When I write

```
sub test (&$$) {
    do_something;
}
```

and call it as

```
test {doing_something_else} 1,2;
```

it works.

When I prototype like this

```
sub test ($$&) {
    do_something;
}
```

and again call it as

```
test 1,2 {doing_something_else};
```

it doesn't work. I tried with various permutations, but nothing seems to deliver.

Am I missing something, or is it not possible? And if not, why?

(I maybe need to specify, that I successfully tried the option of calling test(1, 2, sub{foo}), of course, but it doesn't look quite as sexy as the option in the last example above (and for that I don't even need prototyping); I would like to be able to implement the syntax of structures like if () {} else {}, etc. or, more to the point, try () catch () {} or switch () case (){}, but I guess that's why those constructs have not yet been implemented in Perl)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is [not a good problem description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114574/encourage-problem-descriptions)

Comment: The reason for this in general is parsing ambiguity: perl can't tell whether you meant to call `test $this, $that { BLOCK }` or `test $this, $that{HASHELEM}`.

Comment: @TLP: agreed, still catching up with the syntax here;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `&` prototype character only takes the block form when it is the first item in a prototype.  This is just a limitation of the way perl's prototype parser works.

You could always use the `sub` keyword to create an anonymous subroutine that works fine as an argument in any position without a prototype.

```
test 1, 2, sub {doing_something_else};
```

If you really really want to write it without the `sub` but not in the first position, you could have fun playing around with Devel::Declare to write your own parse rules for the test subroutine (this is an advanced topic).

Comment: Thanks for the Devel::Declare, I reckon I will rewrite the language a bit;-) Or at least fail magnificently...

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the documentation (`perldoc perlsub`):

> An "&" requires an anonymous subroutine, which, if passed as the **first**
>   argument, does not require the "sub" keyword or a subsequent comma.